# What happened to the 3CCD camcorders?

Tags: camcorder, image-sensors

Back in the day they were everywhere [There was even a handheld Panasonic one!] but today they dont exist at all?

I can't find any 3CCD camcorders with SD card video recording because I don't want to fiddle with Mini DV

What happened? Are there any Full HD or 4k 3CCD camcorders these days?

Looks like the ugly CMOS replaced them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The ugly CMOS replaced CCD" because of cost, complexity, power consumption, pixel density, light sensitivity, etc. In every regard — except of the rolling shutter artefacts, of course — CMOS sensors are better. They also do not exhibit the saturation trail effect, the vertical "ray of light" that occurs when pointing a CCD camera towards very bright light source.

You can find a 10-year old tapeless 3CCD-based camcorder on eBay for less than $100. For example, Panasonic HDC-SD5 or HDC-SD9, the latter records progressive HD at 24 fps. Better than Super8 ;-)

Comment: ah my the way. Not so related but does new CMOS sensors have the same dynamic range etc of their CCD ancestors?

Comment: Everything is better aside of nasty rolling shutter artefacts — jello, skewing, flash banding.